# Send SMS for Calendar multi-day events

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

We have a team calendar which contains multi-day events.  We would like to send a daily SMS reminder at UTC +2 /9 a.m. (using Twilio or Google for Apps).

Unfortunately, the multi-day events start at 00:00:00.

Any idea how to approach this?
Is there an easy solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're planning on implementing this on the AppScript side, unfortunately, the solution would be anything but easy. Since Google discontinued [SMS Services](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/45351?hl=en) for reminders, it looks like Twilio is your only viable option of the two in order to send those messages. You would need to read Calendar for the events and using [Time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers), send out a SMS to each member for those events. However, the logic of how to propagate these texts to the right people(according to attendees of the meeting) needs to be figured out as the contacts for Sending out these texts will be stored in Twilio.

However, using the combination of [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) in order to receive the required information and using [Twilio Appointment Reminder](https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/walkthrough/appointment-reminders/java/spark) in order to send out the needed reminders might be a better option to look into.